# How to pass two ints to a constructor using a jvalue array?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I’m trying to create an instance of an object that has a constructor that takes two ints by passing the ints in as members of a jvalue array. When I print the arguments from the constructor it appears that only the first argument is being passed correctly, why would this be? My C and Java code is below.

C code

```
jclass theClass;
jmethodID theMethod;
theClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "thepackage/TwoNumbers");
theMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, theClass, "<init>", "(II)V");

jvalue args[2];
args[0].i=55;
args[1].i=6;

jobject theObj = (*env)->NewObject(env, theClass, theMethod, *args);
```

Java code

```
package thepackage;
public class TwoNumbers {
    int a;
    int b;

    TwoNumbers(int first, int second) {
        this.a=first;
        this.b=second;
        System.out.println("A is "+first+" and b is "+second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function `NewObject` which takes a variable length parameter list.  To utilize the jvalue argument version, you must call `NewObjectA`.

```
jobject theObj=(*env)->NewObjectA(env,theClass,theMethod,*args);
```

See [Documentation - NewObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp23720)